# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration when importing a feature module

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I built an Angular application [MASTER]. Inside of it, I would like to import another application built with a feature module [FEATURE_MODULE].

To generate the FEATURE_MODULE, I followed this tutorial: [Modules tutorial](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/feature-modules.html). This exports a feature module called 'SharedModule' (see tutorial). I included the EagerComponent to this module in order to be imported into the MASTER.

By other hand, I followed the steps mentioned inside this another tutorial to generate a library component (bundle): [How to build a component tutorial](https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e)

Finally, I imported that component into MASTER but when I run it, Angular shows the below message.

> My question is:

How can I import, and use, a component which is included inside a feature module?

App.module.ts:

```
imports: [... , SharedModule.forRoot(), ...],
declarations: [.., EagerComponent, ...]
```

The 'EagerComponent' is the component which I would like to use into MASTER.

Output:

> looking for modules in C:\entorno\diciembreALG\src
>
> using description file: ...\package.json (relative path: ./src)
>
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration after using description file: ...\package.json (relative path: ./src)
>
> using description file: ...\package.json (relative path: ./src/lazy-eager/src/app/eager.component) no extension
>
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration          C:\entorno\diciembreALG\src\lazy-eager\src\app\eager.component doesn't
>
> exist
>   .ts
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 ...\src\lazy-eager\src\app\eager.component.ts doesn't exist
>
> .js
>                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
>                 ...\src\lazy-eager\src\app\eager.component.js doesn't exist
>
> as directory
>                 ...\src\lazy-eager\src\app\eager.component doesn't exist

Angular version:

> Angular CLI: 1.6.1
>
> Node: 9.1.0
>
> OS: win32 x64
>
> Angular: 5.1.1
>
> ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
>
> ... http, language-service, platform-browser
>
> ... platform-browser-dynamic, router
>
> @angular/cdk: 5.0.1
>
> @angular/cli: 1.6.1
>
> @angular/material: 5.0.1
>
> @angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
>
> @angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
>
> @angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
>
> @ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
>
> @ngtools/webpack: 1.9.1
>
> @schematics/angular: 0.1.11
>
> @schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
>
> typescript: 2.4.2
>
> webpack: 3.10.0